# INSERT INTO таблицу поле данные если поле пустое

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы и из одной в другую были перенесены данные:

```
INSERT INTO xf_bdmedal_medal (medal_id, name, description,category_id)
SELECT id,name,longdesc,parent FROM z_jlogica_awards;
```

после чего в description некоторые  поля остались пустые

Нужно повторить Инсерт так чтобы заполнились только пустые description поля а не пустые остались нетронутыми.

Comment: И в чём вопрос?

Comment: Поправил первый пост

Comment: INSERT INTO `xf_bdmedal_medal` (description)
SELECT `desc` FROM `zasm_test`.`z_jlogica_awards` WHERE parent='1';    ----- Данный запрос почему то - MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк)

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь интересовался не тем, как заполнить пустые поля со второй попытки, а тем, почему они не заполнились с первого раза. Если такое происходит, то лучше вообще удалить базу и выключить компьютер, пока ничего не взорвалось :)

Comment: Вы не поняли сути дела. подобные советы с выключением компа оставьте при себе тут вроде все взрослые

Answer (score 2):

Вот необходимый вам запрос:

```
update xf_bdmedal_medal m
join z_jlogica_awards a on a.id=m.medal_id
set description=a.longdesc
where m.description is null and a.longdesc is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу можно решить следующим запросом:

```
update xf_bdmedal_medal xf
set
description=zj.longdesc
from z_jlogica_awards zj
where 
zj.id=xf.medal_id and xf.description is null;
```

Comment: ** UPDATE xf_bdmedal_medal SET description=z_jlogica_awards.longdesc
FROM z_jlogica_awards WHERE z_jlogica_awards.id=xf_bdmedal_medal.medal_id AND xf_bdmedal_medal.description IS NULL; **

Спасибо но не работает  - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: попробую поменять